# can indexing way possible to get class property value or how to get rid of helper method 'GetValue'

Tags: c#

I have below code,

```
var data = new Dictionary<string, TestData>
            {
                { "A1", new TestData { Name = "N1", Section = "S1" } },
                { "A2", new TestData { Name = "N2", Section = "S2" } }
            };

            var strArray = new string[2] { "Name", "Section" };

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, TestData> entry in data)
            {
                foreach (string value in strArray)
                {
                    var X = GetValue(value, entry.Value);
                }
            }

private static string GetValue(string value, TestData data)
    {
        string val = string.Empty;

        if(value == "Name")
        {
            val = data.Name;
        }

        if (value == "Section")
        {
            val = data.Section;
        }

        return val;
    }
```

Here class property and string array has same name `Name` and `Section` and I'm using little helper method to get class property value `GetValue(value, entry.Value)`.

Question, Is there way to get rid of helper method `GetValue` or kind of any way like index, `var X = entry.Value[value];`

Comment: Reflection is your built-in option.

Comment: how, could you please post code

Comment: Can you explain, in plain English, what you want to do? Iterating through a dictionary is probably not the most efficient way to do whatever you want to do, reflection or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection):

```
var entryName = entry.Value.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(entry.Value, null);
var entrySection = entry.Value.GetType().GetProperty("Section").GetValue(entry.Value, null);
```

So in your code would be:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, TestData> entry in data)
{
    var entryName = entry.Value.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(entry.Value, null);
    var entrySection = entry.Value.GetType().GetProperty("Section").GetValue(entry.Value, null);
}
```

Comment: @user584018 Do you have `public string Name { get; set; }` in your TestData class? Or just `public string Name;`? `get` is needed.

Comment: @user584018 do you have any other type of objects in your `foreach`? Because this should not throw...

Comment: here is my class `public class TestData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Section { get; set; }
    }`

Comment: `foreach (KeyValuePair<string, TestData> entry in data)
                {
                    foreach (string value in strArray)
                    {
                        var X = entry.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(entry.Value);
                    }
                }`

Comment: @user584018 I edited my answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two methods whether you can add it directly to the class or if you need to use an extension method.

I should mention that this will just throw an exception if your string is not a property. You need to do some checking.

```
public class TestData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }

    public string Value(string value)
    {
        var val = typeof(TestData).GetProperty(value).GetValue(this);

        // This will return null instead of throwing an exception
        // var val = typeof(TestData).GetProperty(value)?.GetValue(this);

        if (val is string result)
        {
            return result;
        }

        return default;
    }
}
```

Or with the extension method

```
public static class TestDataExtensions
{
    public static string Value(this TestData testData, string value)
    {
        var val = typeof(TestData).GetProperty(value).GetValue(testData);

        if (val is string result)
        {
            return result;
        }

        return default;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There was the `.Value` missing on the reflection approach:

```
var entryName = entry.Value.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(entry.Value, null);
var entrySection = entry.Value.GetType().GetProperty("Section").GetValue(entry.Value, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Work for all types.

```
        var data = new Dictionary<string, TestData>
        {
            { "A1", new TestData { Name = "N1", Section = "S1" } },
            { "A2", new TestData { Name = "N2", Section = "S2" } }
        };

        var strArray = new string[2] { "Name1", "Section" };

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, TestData> entry in data)
        {
            foreach (string value in strArray)
            {
                var x = entry.Value.GetValueByName(value);
            }
        }

public static class GetValueByNameExtension
{
    private static object thisLock = new object();
    private static Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo[]> table = new Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo[]>();

    public static object GetValueByName(this object obj, string propertyName)
    {
        var t = obj.GetType();

        lock(thisLock)
        {
            if (!table.ContainsKey(t.FullName))
            {
                table.Add(t.FullName, t.GetProperties());
            }
        }

        return table[t.FullName].First((x) => x.Name == propertyName).GetValue(obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get a list of all the properties, and iterate through them like this:

```
        var properties = typeof(TestData).GetProperties();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, TestData> entry in data)
        {
            foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
            {
                var X = propertyInfo.GetValue(entry.Value);
            }
        }
```